# in VB.NET with LINQ to XML on where clause set case insensitive comparsion between attributes value and string

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

In Vb.Net using LINQ to XML, i am trying to set on the where clause, a case insensitive comparsion and i get (Object reference is not an instance of an object).

```
 Dim CSFilePathName As String = File.ToString
                Dim CSDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(CSFilePathName)
                Dim CSquery2 As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From element In CSDoc.Root.Descendants
                                                           Where element.@Column.Equals(RichTextBox8.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                                           Select element
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is the sample of XML you are dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

You will get this exception when the `Column` attribute does not exist on the XElement. Take for example this XML:

```xml
<root>
  <child Column="1">Column1</child>
  <child>No Column</child>
</root>
```

This would throw the exception because the second `<child>` does not have the `Column` attribute.

To address this, you'll need to check if the attribute exists first:

```vb
Dim CSquery2 As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From element In CSDoc.Root.Descendants
                                           Where element.Attribute("Column") IsNot Nothing AndAlso element.@Column.Equals(RichTextBox8.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                           Select element
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1nk8r

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with .Equals.

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <root>
                             <child Column="a">Column1</child>
                             <child>No column attribute</child>
                             <child Column="A">Column1</child>
                         </root>
```

Using that data try this,

```
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From element In xe.Elements
            Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.@Column) AndAlso
              element.@Column.Equals("a", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            Select element
```

Note that this works

```
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From element In xe.Elements
            Where element.@Column = "a" OrElse element.@Column = "A"
            Select element
```